# table:last-child not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have something like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First table</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Second table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the following CSS

```
table {
  margin-bottom:40px;
}
table:last-child {
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

But the second table still gets margin-bottom applied. Wat do?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/hgmjF/) (tested in Chrome). Either you are using a browser that doesn't support `:last-child` or your reduced test case has been reduced so far that it can't recreate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Quentin is right that your code does not reproduce your described problem.

I'm going to guess what the problem is.

`table:last-child` does not mean "the last `table` in the parent element".

It actually means "the last element in the parent element **if it's a `table`**".

For example, given this HTML `table:last-child` will not select anything:

```
<div>
    <table>
        ..
    </table>

    <table>
        ..
    </table>

    <div>I'm the last child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I was under the impression that table:last-child was the last <table> element in parent.

Comment: No problem - it's a fairly common misunderstanding. @Hierow's answer should work for you, and `:last-of-type` and `:last-child` have virtually the same browser support.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use `table:last-of-type`.

Both selectors won't work in IE8 and lower